# node not showings single details in postman with params

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, parameters, postman

### In my react project i need fetch single details to details page with params but the response not sending to postman.after sending request the response not coming in postman

```
index.js
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import { userRouter } from "./routes/users.js"
import { recipesRouter } from "./routes/recipes.js"
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.use(cors());

 app.use("/auth", userRouter);
 app.use("/recipes", recipesRouter);

mongoose.connect(
"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
);
app.listen(3001, () => console.log("SERVER STARTED"));
```

router

```
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import { RecipeModel } from "../models/Recipes.js"
import { UserModel } from "../models/User.js";
const router = express.Router();
router.get("/createrecipe/:id",  async (req, res) =>{
let result =await RecipeModel.findOne({id:req.params.id});
if(result){
    res.send(result)
}else{
    res.send('no recipe')
}})
```

postman
`get--http://localhost:3001/createrecipe/1`

```
<body>
    <pre>Cannot GET /createrecipe/1</pre>
</body>
```

need to see the single details in details page and postman.

Comment: Moderators at strike https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389811/moderation-strike-stack-overflow-inc-cannot-consistently-ignore-mistreat-an - so I also will not do **any** (further) content/curation-related action here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `app.use("/recipes", recipesRouter)` You are prefixing all routes in `recipesRouter` with `/recipes` but you are calling `http://localhost:3001/createrecipe/1` instead of `http://localhost:3001/recipes/createrecipe/1`

Comment: thanks for your answer but after that the response is like that"{}"...Not showing the single details in data